# Auto-reload Unity player (from scratch) after saving script?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I know Unity has an auto-refresh feature–but this doesn't restart the player from scratch. As far as I can tell, code in the `Awake()` or `Start()` hooks will not get run again after a script change.

I am building dynamic UIs based on web data for an online game, and I would like to be able to see changes automatically after saving a script. For now, I have to hit the play button manually.

Is this possible? Apologies if this is obvious. I'm new to Unity and have had a good look around the web!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in [`OnValidate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) method of `Monobehaviour`.

Like this:

```
void OnValidate()
{
    // do your stuff here.
}
```

**OR**

you can use `ExecuteInEditMode` attribute on your script.

Like this:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    void Update() {
        if (target)
            transform.LookAt(target);

    }
}
```